# Efficient set data structure supporting insert and set equal

Tags: data-structures, hash, equality

What's the best way to represent sets that support the following two operations:

1. Insert(s, i)  - adds nonnegative integer i to set s
2. Equal(s1, s2) - Tests if s1 and s2 are the same set.

In addition, I have an upper bound on the integers added to each set. That is, I know $N$ such that $0 \le i < N$.

I'm also willing to accept that Equal is only approximate. ie Equal(s1,s2) could be true even if s1 != s2. I guess in that case I'm looking for a hash function. Does anyone know a good hash function?

We can assume that an integer is only inserted once into a set. $N$ can be about 3-5 million, and the number of sets I want to test for equality can be in the thousands.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F$ be a [finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) with efficient procedures for addition and

multiplication and almost-uniform sampling. $\:$ Let $z$ be a field element.

(I use that letter because things will be slightly more convenient if $z$ is

the zero element, although efficient sampling means that even if one

can't find the zero of $F\hspace{-0.03 in}$, one should still be able to find *a* field element.)

To initialize the data structure, sample a field element $x$.

Empty sets are represented by $z$, `Insert(s,i)` adds $x^i$ to the representation of s,

and `Equal(s1,s2)` just tests if the two representing field elements are equal.

Since addition is associative and commutative, there are no false negatives. $\:$ If each integer is only inserted once into a set, then the probability of there being at least one false positive is at most

the [distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) from $x$'s distribution to uniform $\;+\;$ $((N\cdot \text{number of equality tests})\hspace{.02 in}/($[$\hspace{-0.03 in}\operatorname{card}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality)$(F\hspace{.03 in})) \;\;$.

To efficiently compute $x^i\hspace{-0.04 in}$, see [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.106.5081&rep=rep1&type=pdf), and either avoid the methods that involve negative

powers or make slightly stronger assumptions on $F$. $\:$ I would recommend 5.1 on page 14.

Comment: This assumes that there are no duplicates. Also, this is just a special case of the method of adding the outputs of a hash function.

Comment: See the OP: "We can assume that an integer is only inserted once into a set." $\:$ It's a quite useful special case, since it gives provable error bounds. $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed to add the same value more than once, then the insert operation can add the hash value of $i$ to some accumulator associated with $s$, and the equality testing can compare the accumulators.

If you are allowed to add the same value twice, you can use [Bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Comment: Isn't a bloom filter used to represent a **single** set, and efficiently test membership in that set? In my problem I have multiple sets and want to test if two sets are equal.

Comment: You'll use one Bloom filter per set.

Comment: Why would I want to use a Bloom filter for each set, when I don't care about testing membership in the set? That seems like overkill to me.

Comment: @foobarbazquxx : $\;\;\;$ If the data structure needs to support inserting the same value more than once to the same set, then the data structure must suffice for testing membership. $\:$ (Just use Equal(Insert(s,i),s).) $\:$ If the data structure does not need to support that (or the data structure is allowed to represent [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)s instead of sets) then you can use less memory per set. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @foobarbazquxx Bloom filters are just a different way of using hashing, generalizing Juho's approach in their answer. With the correct parameters they sound like a reasonable approach to me.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus So Equal(s1, s2) would just test if two bloom filter's bit arrays were equal?

Comment: @foobarbazquxx That's the idea. You can probably analyze the probability that ``equal`` returns the wrong answer, under the assumption that the hash function is random and independent of the contents of the sets.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $N$ is not too large, consider using a bitvector. For example, you can use a single integer type as a data structure, or an array of bits. Insertion can be done in constant time, and equality checking is very fast as well.

Comment: This solution works even if there are duplicate elements. Just use bitwise OR. If $N$ is large then you can replace your bitvector with a Bloom filter (in which indices are decided by applying a hash function).

Comment: N is on the order of 3 to 5 million

Answer (score 1):

I'll add an additional suggestion based on @Mihai's answer to [this similar cstheory.se question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3390/is-there-a-hash-function-for-a-collection-i-e-multi-set-of-integers-that-has).

If each object in the set has a unique hash, then any commutative operation on the hashes of the members of the set will produce a decent insertion-order independent hash of the entire set.  @Yuval's Bloom filters can be viewed as using the bitwise "or" operator.  @Juho's approach is also using the bitwise "or" operator and the element hash is just the "one-hot" encoding of each member of the set.  @Mihai is suggesting that the encoding of a member $i$ of the set be $a^i \mod p$, for some preselected $a$ that is relatively prime to $p$, and that the commutative operator be addition $\mod p$.  If $p$ is larger than $N$ then the probability of a false equality between two different sets is $O(N/p)$ (according to @Mihai's answer).  I'm sure that there are situations in which bitwise "xor" works as the commutative operator too.

Comment: $\operatorname{lg}_2$ is strictly increasing, so the sentence involving it can be simplified. $\;$

Comment: Won't using bitwise OR eventually converge the entire bitset to be set to 1?

Answer (score 0):

for bitvectors the number of items is not really important, 5 million bits can be stored in 1 megabyte. you should look at the total length of the biggest number or find a mapping into smaller numbers.

For comparison you can calculate the hash over this bitvector.

Comment: Every number between 0 and N can appear in a set, so I'm not sure what you mean by mapping into smaller numbers. If each set requires a MB bitvector and I want to have several thousand sets I'll need several GBs of memory. Unfortunately, that's too expensive, so some kind of hash seems necessary.